# Different results for list comprehension of files in directory compared to traditional loop

Tags: python, list, compression

I need to obtain all the file is a directory and its sub-directories. I'm curious as to why I am getting different results from what I think should be two equivalent python expression. If anyone can explain the difference it would be helpful. Not that I am partial to any particular method but I would like to at least know how to properly write a list comprehension for this.

Here is the loop expression that gives me the results that I need:

```
result = []
for dirpath,subdir,files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        if '.nc' in filename:
            result.append(filename)
```

So the length of the resulting list in my case is 1533 which is the correct number. Now using what I think is the equivalent list comprehension would be:

```
result = [filename for filename in files if '.nc' in filename for dirpath,subdir,files in os.walk(directory)]
```

The length of this resulting list is 2480 and the reason for this is that there are duplicate files included. Why is this expression not equivalent to the one above? I know this example isn't too concrete as it depends on what directory is being used but you can try replacing `directory` with a file path to a given folder and `'.nc'` to `'.txt'` or some string that is present in a bunch of files within the folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
import os.path

result = [
    os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
    for dirpath, _, files in os.walk(directory)
    for filename in files if '.nc' in filename
]
```

You have your loops in the wrong order in the list comprehension. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551458/how-to-frame-two-for-loops-in-list-comprehension-python) for reference on the syntax. My quick rule of thumb for you is to write the loops in the order you would if it were not a list comprehension and then to put the ouput expression at the start.

I added `os.path.join` because it seemed likely you want the complete path.

If you just want the total number of such matching files, you can do this:

```
result = sum(1
    for dirpath, _, files in os.walk(directory)
    for filename in files if '.nc' in filename
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes a lot more sense now. I really only need the number of files (there's probably an easier way), but my question was basically to understand the syntax for nested for loops in list comprehensions