# Outputting items in two combined lists in descending numerical order?

Tags: python, arrays, file-io, text-files

I have a txt file that looks like this:

> Raj,Joy:9,8,1
>
> Smith,John:8
>
> Campbell,Michelle:5,7,9

NOTE: There is no empty lines between the lines of text in the text file

I want to output each result of each person in descending numerical order, e.g.

> Campbell,Michelle:9
>
> Raj,Joy:9
>
> Raj,Joy:8
>
> Smith,John:8
>
> Campbell,Michelle:7
>
> etc.

The code I have so far is this:

```
            data = src.readlines()
            for line in data:
                record = line.split(':')
                scoreList = record[1].split(',')
                # Add name to fileRecord
                for n in scoreList:
                    fileRecord.append(record[0])

                # Two dimensional list created, each item is one set of scores
                fileScores.append(scoreList)
```

where src is the text file.
The main problem posed for me is if I invoke .sort() on sortList I lose the order and so cannot match each score with its corresponding name. If I were to create a dictionary the problem posed is outputting the sorted data individually as sorting

> {"Raj,Joy":[9,8,1],etc}

would not sort it by each individual score that "Raj,Joy" got, but I cant split the list because then I would have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have filled `fileRecord` and `fileScores`. Now you combine them and sort:

```
>>> fileRecord = ['Raj,Joy', 'Smith,John', 'Campbell,Michelle']

>>> fileScores = [[9, 8, 1], [8], [5, 7, 9]]

>>> comb = []

>>> for record, scores in zip(fileRecord, fileScores):
...     for score in scores:
...         comb.append((record, score))
...         

>>> comb
>>> 
[('Raj,Joy', 9),
 ('Raj,Joy', 8),
 ('Raj,Joy', 1),
 ('Smith,John', 8),
 ('Campbell,Michelle', 5),
 ('Campbell,Michelle', 7),
 ('Campbell,Michelle', 9)]

>>> comb.sort(key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)

>>> comb
>>> 
[('Raj,Joy', 9),
 ('Campbell,Michelle', 9),
 ('Raj,Joy', 8),
 ('Smith,John', 8),
 ('Campbell,Michelle', 7),
 ('Campbell,Michelle', 5),
 ('Raj,Joy', 1)]
```

You would want to use `itertools.izip` instead of the built-in `zip` in Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

Open the file and `str.rpartition` each line to isolate the numbers from the name. Then build a generator to expand name with each of its numbers, sort that, then do whatever you need for outputting, eg:

**Code:**

```
with open('input_file') as fin:
    name_nums = (line.rpartition(':')[::2] for line in fin)
    expanded = ((name, int(n)) for name, num in name_nums for n in num.split(','))
    ordered = sorted(expanded, key=lambda L: L[1], reverse=True)
    for name, num in ordered:
        print '{}:{}'.format(name, num)
```

**Output**:

```
Raj,Joy:9
Campbell,Michelle:9
Raj,Joy:8
Smith,John:8
Campbell,Michelle:7
Campbell,Michelle:5
Raj,Joy:1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` function with a desire `key` :

```
>>> s="""Raj,Joy:9,8,1
... 
... Smith,John:8
... 
... Campbell,Michelle:5,7,9"""

>>> l=s.split('\n\n')
>>> from itertools import chain    
>>> for i in sorted(chain(*[[(i[0],j) for j in i[1].split(',')] for i in [i.split(':') for i in l]]),key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True) :
...   print ':'.join(i)
... 
Raj,Joy:9
Campbell,Michelle:9
Raj,Joy:8
Smith,John:8
Campbell,Michelle:7
Campbell,Michelle:5
Raj,Joy:1
```

So all we have down in above one line code if as below :

first we split the text with tow new line ('\n\n') and put it in `l` :

```
l=s.split('\n\n') 
>>> l
['Raj,Joy:9,8,1', 'Smith,John:8', 'Campbell,Michelle:5,7,9']
```

then you need to create a list of pairs contain the names and scores :

```
>>> [[(i[0],j) for j in i[1].split(',')] for i in [i.split(':') for i in l]]
[[('Raj,Joy', '9'), ('Raj,Joy', '8'), ('Raj,Joy', '1')], [('Smith,John', '8')], [('Campbell,Michelle', '5'), ('Campbell,Michelle', '7'), ('Campbell,Michelle', '9')]]
```

and at last you need to first chain the nested lists and then sort this list based on second element (score) with sorted function and the following key :

```
key=lambda x: x[1]
```

and if you want to write to file :

```
with open ('sample_file','w') as f :
     for i in sorted(chain(*[[(i[0],j) for j in i[1].split(',')] for i in [i.split(':') for i in l]]),key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True) :
        f.write(':'.join(i))
```

Comment: This doesn't match the OPs output - the names should be output multiple times per score it appears

Comment: @KasraAD Perhaps we could create multiple dictonaries to avoid duplicate keys, but it is very inefficient and overly complex, especially when sorting it.

Comment: @KasraAD could you explain your edit please because I dont understand it

Comment: @joyalrj22 yes surely , pls wait !

Comment: @KasraAD is it possible to replace the.split() methods with  record = line.split(':'), scoreList = record[1].split(',')

Comment: @joyalrj22  i replace it some part of code was extra , check out the edit

Answer (score 0):

```
s = """Raj,Joy:9,8,1
Smith,John:8
Campbell,Michelle:5,7,9"""
```

Use getKey to provide tuples second element as key to sorted()

```
def getKey(item):
    return item[1]
```

Declare your list objects

```
asc_list = []
result = []
```

Use list comprehension to split input into separate lines:

```
asc_list = [i for i in s.split("\n")]
asc_list = [(j.split(':')[0],k) for j in asc_list for k in j.split(':')[1].split(',')]
```

Use sorted to sort on tuple item number 2

```
result =  sorted(asc_list_nums, key=getKey)
```

Output:

```
[('Raj,Joy', '1'), ('Campbell,Michelle', '5'), ('Campbell,Michelle', '7'), ('Raj,Joy', '8'), ('Smith,John', '8'), ('Raj,Joy', '9'), ('Campbell,Michelle', '9')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect example for a Python one-liner. Applying list comprehensions and built-in `sorted` function.

Flattening the combined lists into a list of tuples

```
scores = [(record, score) for record, scores in zip(fileRecord, fileScores) for score in scores]
```

Sort list of tuples by score in descending order

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(scores, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Problem solved in a single line

```
sorted([(record, score) for record, scores in zip(fileRecord, fileScores) for score in scores], key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Useful References

- [Nested list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551458/how-to-frame-two-for-loops-in-list-comprehension-python)
- [Sorting Mini How-To](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)
- [operator module functions allow multiple levels of sorting](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Operator_Module_Functions)