# Python: explanation of single-line for loops

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I understand what this code does. However, I don't understand how the syntax works. I hope that somebody can explain me these loops in detail. Thanks. I appreciate your help

```
minY = min([y for yValues in yAll for y in yValues])
```

```py
xValues = [1,2,3,4] 
yValues0 = [6,7.5,8,7.5] 
yValues1 = [5.5,6.5,50,6] 
yValues2 = [6.5,7,8,7] 
yAll = [yValues0, yValues1, yValues2]  # list of lists 

# flatten list of lists retrieving minimum value 
minY = min([y for yValues in yAll for y in yValues])
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551458/how-to-frame-two-for-loops-in-list-comprehension-python

Comment: Those are called 'list comprehensions', and you can check a lot of material on them online, one of which currently being: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension. Good day to you,