# Unable to comprehend a list comprehension with two loops

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The solution that is working for me for this problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/flipping-an-image/) here is

```py
class Solution:
    def flipAndInvertImage(self, image: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        return [[bit ^ 1 for bit in reversed(row)] for row in image]
```

However , and I feel like I dont understand something about list comprehension here, the following gives me an error:

```py
class Solution:
    def flipAndInvertImage(self, image: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        return [[bit ^ 1] for bit in reversed(row) for row in image]
```

[image]

Why am i getting this error ?, and similarly this does not work either.

```py
class Solution:
    def flipAndInvertImage(self, image: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        return [bit ^ 1 for bit in reversed(row) for row in image]
```

Comment: Attempts 2 and 3 need to flip the `for` loops: `[bit ^ 1 for row in image for bit in reversed(row)]` and the behavior is going to be different, flattening the 2d list. Version 2 doesn't make much sense, you'll get a list of 1-element sublists. Please see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551458/how-to-frame-two-for-loops-in-list-comprehension-python) has some good explanations of list comprehensions with multiple for loops.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

Check [[Python.Docs]: Data Structures - Nested List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions), it contains an example similar to yours.

The rules (they scale indefinitely) that need to be remembered about comprehensions evaluation:

1. Nested: from outer to inner
2. Plain: from left to right

> ```py
> >>> l0 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
> >>> 
> >>> [[i ** 2 for i in l1] for l1 in l0]  # Nested
> [[1, 4, 9], [16, 25, 36]]
> >>> 
> >>> [[i ** 2] for l1 in l0 for i in l1]  # Plain (notice the (reversed) for order)
> [[1], [4], [9], [16], [25], [36]]
> ```

In the example above:

- Nested: Identifiers in the outer scope are visible in the inner one(s): ***l1***
- Plain: Identifiers **must** exist before being referenced: ***l1*** before ***i***